# Read text file and prompt when end of file is reached

Tags: vb.net, messagebox, readline

```
Private Sub btnnext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnnext.Click    
   lblfirst.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lblMiddle.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lbllast.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lblempnum.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lbldept.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lbltele.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lblext.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lblemail.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   lblsal.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   Label10.Text = objstreamreader.ReadLine
   If (objstreamreader.ReadLine) = -1 Then
      'no department has been selected
      MessageBox.Show("There are no more records on file")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i cant seem to get the msgbox to prompt the user that the end of the record has been reached** @enderlaned

Comment: im using visual studios 2012

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MessageBox.Show("There are no more records on file")`, how about `MsgBox("There are no more records on file")`?